# HTML/Javascript Average Mark

Tags: javascript, html, average, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the average marks that are entered in the textboxes, but when I click on the Result button, the average doesn't appear. It might be something in the javascript, but I'm not sure what could be wrong. Do I need to add anything more to the javascript? Appreciate the help.

HTML code

```
<h2>Average Marks</h2>
<p>
<label>Module Grade 1: <input id="grade1" type="text" name="grade1" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 2: <input id="grade2" type="text" name="grade2" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 3: <input id="grade3" type="text" name="grade3" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 4: <input id="grade4" type="text" name="grade4" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 5: <input id="grade5" type="text" name="grade5" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 6: <input id="grade6" type="text" name="grade6" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="avg" onclick="average()" value="Average"/>
<label>Result: <input id="average" type="text" name="average" size ="8" /> </label><br/>
```

Javascript code

```
function average(){
    var grade1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade1").value);
    var grade2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade2").value);
    var grade3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade3").value);
    var grade4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade4").value);
    var grade5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade5").value);
    var grade6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade6").value);


    var add = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6;
    var avg = add / 6;
    document.getElementById("average").value = ave.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten your variable name wrong: its `avg.toFixed` instead of `ave.toFixed`.

```js
function average(){
    var grade1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade1").value);
    var grade2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade2").value);
    var grade3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade3").value);
    var grade4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade4").value);
    var grade5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade5").value);
    var grade6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade6").value);


    var add = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6;
    var avg = add / 6;
    document.getElementById("average").value = avg.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Average Marks</h2>
<p>
<label>Module Grade 1: <input id="grade1" type="text" name="grade1" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 2: <input id="grade2" type="text" name="grade2" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 3: <input id="grade3" type="text" name="grade3" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 4: <input id="grade4" type="text" name="grade4" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 5: <input id="grade5" type="text" name="grade5" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 6: <input id="grade6" type="text" name="grade6" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="avg" onclick="average()" value="Average"/>
<label>Result: <input id="average" type="text" name="average" size ="8" /> </label><br/>
```

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. It's working now, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :).If this (or @sunil) answer helped to solve your problem, feel free to select that answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ave.toFixed(2)
```

to

```
avg.toFixed(2);
```

```js
function average(){
    var grade1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade1").value);
    var grade2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade2").value);
    var grade3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade3").value);
    var grade4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade4").value);
    var grade5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade5").value);
    var grade6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade6").value);


    var add = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6;
    var avg = add / 6;
    document.getElementById("average").value = avg.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Average Marks</h2>
<p>
<label>Module Grade 1: <input id="grade1" type="text" name="grade1" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 2: <input id="grade2" type="text" name="grade2" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 3: <input id="grade3" type="text" name="grade3" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 4: <input id="grade4" type="text" name="grade4" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 5: <input id="grade5" type="text" name="grade5" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />
<label>Module Grade 6: <input id="grade6" type="text" name="grade6" size ="10" /> </label><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="avg" onclick="average()" value="Average"/>
<label>Result: <input id="average" type="text" name="average" size ="8" /> </label><br/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thank you :)